# SWFUpload on upload cycle complete redirect to new url

Tags: php, joomla, swfupload

I'm using SWFUpload in Joomla backend component creation. I can upload
 images with this uploader finely. After Upload cycle completion I
 can't redirect to new url.

When I enter window.location.href="url" after upload call, it
 redirects to the said url but images are not uploaded and server(I/O)
error is displayed.

Anyone please provide me a suggestion.

Comment: Do you know that SWFUpload is no longer included in the CMS? Why don't you use the core image uploading?

Comment: You are correct. But SWFUpload  is suggested in joomla file uploader component so only I have used it

Comment: You understand it is a security hazard? You ahould not be reinstalling it. Why don't you just use a JQuery uploader? Although the core media field also works fine.

Comment: Elin is correct, apart from being a security hazzard, it's also a very buggy uploader. We made a SWFUpload component a long time ago for people to download and use, however due to all the problems, we ended up removing it. I would suggest using the media manager or using an extension from the JED site. Just on a side not, would you mind committing to the [Joomla Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58842/joomla?referrer=Ph_HGDW6OiEqU7r0cS-muA2) for StackExchange if you haven't done so already?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comments. I'm testing in localhost only. I'll change the uploader in the real website.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect in `upload_complete_handler` like this

```
upload_complete_handler: function (file) {
    var num = this.getStats().files_queued ; //num is the count of file in queue
    if(num == 0){
           window.location.href = 'http://url.you.want.to.redirect';
    } else {
        this.startUpload(); //next file in queue
    }
},
```